# Infinite Scroll Plugin: How to first show 6 posts and then 2 posts thereafter with Infinite Scroll Plugin?

Tags: php, pagination

I am using the Infinite Scroll Plugin and initially load 6 posts onto the page. After the user hits "Show More" which is the pagination buttons on the page, I would like for 2 posts to be displayed thereafter.

Here's the query code I am using:

```
<?php
$query = 'category_name=features&groupby=post_date&orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=6&paged='.get_query_var('paged');     
query_posts($query);    
?>
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    if (get_query_var('paged') <= 1) {
        $query = 'category_name=features&groupby=post_date&orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=6&paged='.get_query_var('paged');         
    } else {
        $query = 'category_name=features&groupby=post_date&orderby=date&order=DESC&posts_per_page=2&paged='.get_query_var('paged');         
    }
    query_posts($query);    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a similar problem has received an answer; have you seen it?

[Use two different post_per_page limits with infinite scroll](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51490/use-two-different-post-per-page-limits-with-infinite-scroll)

From that link:

1. Add a parameter to the href URI for the next posts link per JavaScript. For example ?ppp=2.
2. Add a filter to pre_get_posts, check if ppp is set (and a positive integer) and change the post_per_page parameter accordingly.